# Going back to Home Activity from fragment without starting the new Acivity(Home Page)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a fragment which lists the people.It is invoked in an (Main)Activity which launches before PeopleListFragment.On pressing back button, the whole application finishes off.I need to go to the Main Activity instead of closing.I am confused, whether to use PopBackStack(),PopBackStackimmediate() or OnBackPressed().Could anyone help me with this..?

**PeopleListFragment**

```
public class PeopleListFragment extends Fragment implements PeopleController.PeopleListView, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String TAG = "PeopleListFragment";
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Constant.DEBUG;

    private static final String EXTRA_EMPLOYEE_ID = "employeeId";
    private static final String EXTRA_FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    private static final String EXTRA_LAST_NAME = "lastName";

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private ArrayList<People> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView mContactlistView;

    Parcelable state;
    private Intent intent;
    private PeopleAdapter adapter;

    /**
     * Passes the value to another activity/fragment
     *
     * @param employeeId
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @return
     */
    public static PeopleListFragment newInstance(String employeeId, String firstName, String lastName) {

        PeopleListFragment fragment = new PeopleListFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(EXTRA_EMPLOYEE_ID, employeeId);
        args.putString(EXTRA_FIRST_NAME, firstName);
        args.putString(EXTRA_LAST_NAME, lastName);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public PeopleListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Initializing the People controller

        PeopleController.getInstance(getActivity()).addPeopleListCallback(this);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating the layout for people list fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mContactlistView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.people_list);
        mContactlistView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (state != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Restoring list view state");

            mContactlistView.requestFocus();
            mContactlistView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        adapter = new PeopleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.people_list_item, contactList);

        mContactlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mContactlistView.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        mContactlistView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        mContactlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String empId = String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(position).getEmployeeId());
                String fname = String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(position).getFirstName());
                String lname = String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(position).getLastName());

                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        PeopleDetailsActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("EmployeeId", empId);
                intent.putExtra("fName", fname);
                intent.putExtra("lName", lname);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    public void updateListView(ArrayList<People> peopleList) {

        contactList = peopleList;
        adapter.updateItems(contactList);

        if (contactList.size() == 0) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Contact List is Empty");
            }

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        } else {
            mContactlistView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void showProgress() {

        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.show();
            mContactlistView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void displayPeopleList(ArrayList<People> peoples) {
        updateListView(peoples);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePeopleList(ArrayList<People> peoples) {
        updateListView(peoples);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        PeopleController.getInstance(getActivity()).getPeople();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        PeopleController.getInstance(getActivity()).onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        PeopleController.getInstance(getActivity()).onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        PeopleController.getInstance(getActivity()).removePeopleListCallback();
    }

    @Override
    public void showError(int errorCode) {

        if (errorCode == NetworkClient.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED_SESSION) {

            logout();

        } else if (errorCode == NetworkClient.FAILURE) {

            if (contactList.size() == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Empty Contact List",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                //show sync warning
                Snackbar.make(mContactlistView, R.string.info_no_event,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (errorCode == NetworkClient.NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION) {
            if (contactList.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void logout() {
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof BaseActivity) {
            ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).logout();
        }
    }

    public void search(String searchText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(searchText);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        search(newText);
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * In this method the search interface is setup for searching a particular employee
     *
     * @param menu
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    protected static final int NAVDRAWER_ITEM_HOME = 0;
    protected static final int NAVDRAWER_ITEM_PEOPLE = 1;
    protected static final int NAVDRAWER_ITEM_CALENDAR = 2;
    protected static final int NAVDRAWER_ITEM_TRAINING = 3;
    protected static final int NAVDRAWER_ITEM_ANNOUNCEMENT = 4;

    protected static final int NAVDRAWER_ITEM_INVALID = -1;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    Intent intent;

    /**
     * List of Title for each {@link NavigationView} item
     */
    private static final int[] NAVDRAWER_TITLE_RES_ID = {
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.people,
            R.string.calendar,
            R.string.training,
            R.string.announcement
    };

    /**
     * Primary color list for each {@link NavigationView} item
     */
    private static final int[] NAVDRAWER_PRIMARY_COLOR_RES_ID = {
            R.color.trainingPrimaryColor,
            R.color.peoplePrimaryColor,
            R.color.calendarPrimaryColor,
            R.color.trainingPrimaryColor,
            R.color.announcementPrimaryColor
    };

    /**
     * Status bar color list for each {@link NavigationView} item
     */
    private static final int[] NAVDRAWER_PRIMARY_DARK_COLOR_RES_ID = {
            R.color.trainingPrimaryDarkColor,
            R.color.peoplePrimaryDarkColor,
            R.color.calendarPrimaryDarkColor,
            R.color.trainingPrimaryDarkColor,
            R.color.announcementPrimaryDarkColor
    };

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private PeopleListFragment mPeopleListFragment;
    private AnnouncementListFragment mAnnouncementListFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getSelfNavDrawerItem() > 0) {
            setTitle(NAVDRAWER_TITLE_RES_ID[getSelfNavDrawerItem()]);

            setToolbarBackgroundColor(NAVDRAWER_PRIMARY_COLOR_RES_ID[getSelfNavDrawerItem()]);

            setStatusBarColor(NAVDRAWER_PRIMARY_DARK_COLOR_RES_ID[getSelfNavDrawerItem()]);
//            sendScreenName(getString(NAVDRAWER_TITLE_RES_ID[getSelfNavDrawerItem()]));
        }

        initNavDrawer();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize {@link NavigationView} and set Listener for the View
     */
    private void initNavDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (mDrawerLayout == null) {
            return;
        }

        //To display Menu
        NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        // To preserve original icon color in NavigationView
        mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                getToolbar(), R.string.open, R.string.close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                int itemId = NAVDRAWER_ITEM_INVALID;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        itemId = NAVDRAWER_ITEM_HOME;
                        break;

                    case R.id.people:
                        itemId = NAVDRAWER_ITEM_PEOPLE;
                        break;

                    case R.id.calendar:
                        itemId = NAVDRAWER_ITEM_CALENDAR;
                        break;

                    case R.id.training:
                        itemId = NAVDRAWER_ITEM_TRAINING;
                        break;

                    case R.id.announcement:
                        itemId = NAVDRAWER_ITEM_ANNOUNCEMENT;
                        break;
                }

                onNavDrawerItemClicked(itemId);
                return false;
            }
        });

        NavigationMenuView navigationMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) mNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
        //Add a Divider between Menu Items in NavigationView
        navigationMenuView.addItemDecoration(new LineDividerItemDecoration(this, R.drawable.line_divider,
                1));
    }


    /**
     * It return which Navigation view item it displaying/active, if activity does not
     * contain {@link NavigationView} it'll return {@link #NAVDRAWER_ITEM_INVALID}
     *
     * @return Navigation Item ID
     */
    protected int getSelfNavDrawerItem() {
        return NAVDRAWER_ITEM_INVALID;
    }

    /**
     * When {@link NavigationView} item click it'll be called
     *
     * @param itemId Id of clicked item
     */
    private void onNavDrawerItemClicked(final int itemId) {
        if (itemId == getSelfNavDrawerItem()) {
            //if current Navigation Item is clicked again don't do anything simply close the
            // Drawerlayout
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return;
        }

        goToNavDrawerItem(itemId);

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        /*mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                goToNavDrawerItem(itemId);
            }
        }, NAVDRAWER_LANUCH_DELAY);

        View mainContent = findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        if (mainContent != null) {
            mainContent.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(MAIN_CONTENT_FADEOUT_DURATION).start();
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * Start New Activity for clicked item
     *
     * @param itemId Id of clicked item
     */
    private void goToNavDrawerItem(int itemId) {


        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;


        Intent intent = null;

        switch (itemId) {

            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_HOME:

                intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;

                //to clear the activity stack to avoid showing previous activity by pressing back key
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                break;

            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_PEOPLE:
                setTitle("People");
                setStatusBarColor(R.color.peoplePrimaryDarkColor);
                setToolbarBackgroundColor(R.color.peoplePrimaryColor);

                fragmentClass = PeopleListFragment.class;
                break;

            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_CALENDAR:

           //Calendar fragment
                break;

            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_TRAINING:

             //Training fragment
                break;

            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_ANNOUNCEMENT:

                setTitle("Announcement");
                setStatusBarColor(R.color.announcementPrimaryDarkColor);
                setToolbarBackgroundColor(R.color.announcementPrimaryColor);

                fragmentClass = AnnouncementListFragment.class;

                break;
        }


        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) (fragmentClass != null ? fragmentClass.newInstance() : null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.display_frame_container, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        //To cancel the transition animation
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

}
```

**Base Activity**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TrainingListFragment.TrainingCallback {
    /**
     * Drawer Layout for creating {@link NavigationView}
     */

    private Handler mHandler;


    /**
     * Toolbar
     */
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    /**
     * Google Analytical Tracker
     */
    private Tracker mTracker;

    /*private static final int NAVDRAWER_LANUCH_DELAY = 250;

    private static final int MAIN_CONTENT_FADEOUT_DURATION = 250;*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());

        String session = PreferenceUtil.getInstance(this).getSession();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(session)) {
            logout();
        }

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        //Initialize the Google Analytical Tracker
        mTracker = ((INetApplication) getApplication()).getDefaultTracker();


        mHandler = new Handler();


    }

    /**
     * Send Current Activity Name to Google Analytics
     *
     * @param screenName Name of the Current Screen
     */
    protected void sendScreenName(String screenName) {
        mTracker.setScreenName("Activity~" + screenName);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    }

    /**
     * Send Calendar Event to Google Analytics
     *
     * @param value Selected Date
     */
    protected void sendCalendarEventToAnalytics(String value) {
        String CATEGORY_CALENDAR = "Calendar";
        String ACTION_SELECT_DATE = "Select Date";

        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory(CATEGORY_CALENDAR)
                .setAction(ACTION_SELECT_DATE)
                .setLabel(value).build());
    }


    /**
     * To clear the User session and display the Login screen
     */
    public void logout() {
        //clear the session and employee id value from preference
        PreferenceUtil.getInstance(this).setSession("");
        PreferenceUtil.getInstance(this).setEmpId("");

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        //to clear the activity stack to avoid showing previous activity by pressing back key
        loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);

        finish();
    }


    /**
     * It will give the Layout Resource ID
     *
     * @return int value of Layout Resource
     */
    protected abstract
    @LayoutRes
    int getLayoutResourceId();


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //To cancel the transition animation
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*View mainContent = findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        if (mainContent != null) {
            mainContent.setAlpha(0);
            mainContent.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(MAIN_CONTENT_FADEOUT_DURATION).start();
        }*/
    }


    /**
     * To enable/disable HomeUp option in {@link Toolbar}
     *
     * @param isHomeDisplay boolean to change the HomeUp option
     */
    public void setHomeUpEnable(boolean isHomeDisplay) {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(isHomeDisplay);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(isHomeDisplay);
            Drawable backArrowDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,
                    android.support.design.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);

            backArrowDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrowDrawable);

        }
    }

    /**
     * To change the background color of {@link Toolbar}
     *
     * @param colorValue color value
     */
    public void setToolbarBackgroundColor(@ColorRes int colorValue) {
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorValue));
    }

    /**
     * To change the statusbarcolor
     *
     * @param colorValue color value
     */
    public void setStatusBarColor(@ColorRes int colorValue) {
        UIUtil.getInstance(this).setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorValue));
    }

    /**
     * Set the title of this {@link #mToolbar}.
     *
     * @param title title value in string
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mToolbar.setTitle(title);
    }

    /**
     * Set the title of this {@link #mToolbar}.
     *
     * @param title a string resource
     */
    public void setTitle(@StringRes int title) {
        mToolbar.setTitle(title);
    }

    public Toolbar getToolbar() {
        return mToolbar;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTrainingItemClick(String trainingId, String trainingTitle, boolean joinStatus,
                                    String trainingTime) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrainingDetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(TrainingDetailFragment.EXTRA_ID, trainingId);
        intent.putExtra(TrainingDetailFragment.EXTRA_TITLE, trainingTitle);
        intent.putExtra(TrainingDetailFragment.EXTRA_JOINED_STATUS, joinStatus);
        intent.putExtra(TrainingDetailFragment.EXTRA_TRAINING_TIME, trainingTime);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void displayInfoView(int displayCode) {

    }


}
```

Comment: Hope this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326776/mainactivity-to-fragment-and-back-to-mainactivity-on-pressing-back-button/36326830#36326830

Comment: you can use: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using stacks to maintain your fragment then use the stack to pop fragments until your stack size becomes 1

```
while(getParent().stackSize() >2) {
        getParent().popFragments();
    }
```

Comment: while(getParent().stackSize() >2) {
            getParent().popFragments();
        }

Comment: I am not using stack to maintain fragment.Whatever I do, my application closes

Comment: try this then 
while(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 2) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();}

Comment: Sorry I am new to android.I dont know where to use this.Should I try this inside detach method..?

Comment: use it where you want to move to home

Comment: I have uploaded my code.Let me know if you need some other code.

Comment: add me on skype momi_boisterous

Answer (score 0):

To replace fragment use the below code

```
 @Override
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
            //     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }
    }
```

Use this code to add fragment

Add the below line in your Fragment onCreateView

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Use the below code to go back the previous fragment.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to clear all fragment except the first one just do this in for loop  if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() -->showing error like cannot be resolved.Is there any other alternative.?

Comment: Inside a Fragment subclass you have to use getFragmentManager in place of getSupportFragmentManager. You will get the support one if the import are from the support library.

Comment: I have used the above code.But there is no action taking place.Its simply in the same peoplelsitfragment.

Comment: Do you want to go to the main activity or main fragment?...if your fragment classes is second activity you have to remove finish(); from your first activity intent call..if you wanna go to the main fragment from the current fragment you have to use the above code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the transaction to backstack then only fragment will be poped.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.display_frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

this to

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.display_frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack("").commit();
```

when you press back button it will automatically goes to MainActivity

Comment: No..its not navigating back to MainActivity.